# Visual rich snippets for repeating events with JSON-LD and ISO 8601 notation

Tags: schema.org, iso8601, rich-snippets, google-rich-snippets, json-ld

Will visual rich snippets be generated for repeating events, which are negotiated with ISO 8601 notation for repeating dates, like this

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
 {
   "@context": "http://schema.org",
   "@type": "event",
   "name":  "My regular Event",
   "startDate": "R2/2014-10-14T18:30:00Z+01/P1W"
 }
</script>
```

Comment: are you referring to the rich snippets specified by google?

Comment: @AbelMelquiadesCallejo yes

Comment: Your `@type` should be `Event` and not `event`. Those two are different.

Answer (score 2):

No, that is not the way to do it. The description of [schema.org/Event](http://schema.org/Event) suggests you to treat repeating events as separate events.

**schema.org/Event**

> An event happening at a certain time and location, such as a concert, lecture, or festival. Ticketing information may be added via the 'offers' property. Repeated events may be structured as separate Event objects.

What you can do is to create two separate events like so:

**My regular Event - part 1**

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
        "@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@type": "Event",
        "name":  "My regular Event - part 1",
        "startDate": "2014-10-14T18:30:00.0Z"
    }
</script>
```

**My regular Event - part 2**

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
        "@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@type": "Event",
        "name":  "My regular Event - part 2",
        "startDate": "2014-10-21T18:30:00.0Z"
    }
</script>
```

However, [Google's Rich Snippets specifications](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/99170?hl=en) don't directly say JSON-LD is supported.